# RestFB : How to get all of a facebook users posts using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, restfb

When i use the following query https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1347629308665541/feed?limit=100&access_token=146055952628403%7CZLntKASz1sjS1y8ZLKVFnfFRE400&format=json

I get 0 posts from graph api, I tried using the User Access Token, the Page Access Token as well as the Application token, but I don't get any posts.

1347629308665541 is a facebook users UserId which i have fetched by getting the users who like a particular facebook POST.

Is it possible to get a feed of all the posts of the user who has liked my facebook post? I have a user access token or page access token available if needed.

Comment: The user would need to grant your app permission to read their posts first - so that means login.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access token with:

1. Login to your facebook
2. Go to your profile page
3. Right click to "View Page Source"
4. Find text with key: "access_token"